# CMake, .dll vs .dll.a vs .a: What library should I specify in the CMake configuration?

Tags: opencv, cmake, openblas

I am working on Windows 10 and CMake 3.14.1.

I am trying to build OpenCV (Version 4.0.1) myself, since I need the contrib modules and the SFM module. I downloaded a prebuilt version of openBLAS 0.2.19. It has 3 directories, **bin**, **include**, and **lib**.
The bin directory includes libopenblas.dll, include has the headers and in lib there are libopenblas.a and libopenblas.dll.a (and a cmake directory).

When I'm configuring openCV with CMake, of course I set openBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR to the include directory. But which file should I specify to openBLAS_LIB? libopenblas.dll, libopenblas.a or libopenblas.dll.a?

And later on when I'm building openCV (with Visual Studio 2017), where should I put the .dll so that it is visible to the building process?

Edit: Maybe I should add that OpenBLAS was compiled with minGW, that's why there are those weird .a and .dll.a files instead of .lib

Answer (score 6):

I can now at least partially answer my question. Those two answers have helped me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139061/6793721

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6480464/6793721

So `.a` files are usually the Unix static libraries, for Windows we have `.lib`. Since minGW uses GCC, it produces `.a` libraries, but in a way that they are compatible with Visual Studio and MSVC. So I guess `libopenblas.a` is the full *static* library, and `libopenblas.dll.a` is the *import* library to be used with `libopenblas.dll`.
Now when building openCV, in CMake I specified `libopenblas.dll.a` as the library and everything worked (configuring, building, installing). I did add the directory where the `.dll` is located to the PATH, but I'm not sure if that needs to be done or is the best way to do it.