# Callback functions in client dll of Citrix virtual channel are not called

Tags: c, citrix, compiler-flags, virtual-channel

I have the following problem: I've created client DLL with all needed callback functions (`DriverOpen`, `DriverClose` etc.). But they are not called, and I, actually, don't know why. Test `dll vdping` is working fine. May be the thing is I use VS2010 to build that DLL? Or should I use any specific compiler or link flags?

Comment: what does it mean 'they are not called'? Did you export those functions from the dll? Use __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: @dousin Is it equivalent of .def files?

Comment: in general yes, but note, it is possible to export 'extern "C"{}' methods, since exact match is needed between method name and the name in def file. So, useless for mangeled names. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366228/def-files-c-c-dlls