# Changing a function signature in DEF file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, name-mangling

I'm changing signature of a function which will be exported in dll.

DEF file:

```
...
??0CLimitOrderBase@Base@@QEAA@H@Z
?foo@CLimitOrderBase@Base@@UEAAHAEAVCLimitInfo@2@@Z
...
```

Code will change from

```
namespace Base {

class CLimitOrderBase : public CLimit
{
    ...
    virtual BOOL foo(CLimitInfo &limitInfo);
    ...
};
```

to

```
virtual BOOL foo(CLimitInfo &limitInfo, bool bCheck = false);
```

How do I get the new mangled name to change in the DEF file?

Comment: Why not to declare your class as `__declspec(dllexport)` and forget about manually exporting functions having mangled names?

Comment: You change it with a text editor.  Use the linker's .map file to see the new name.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to a header file which every other header file from your DLL includes (renaming YOURDLL with something meaningful):

```
#ifdef YOURDLL_EXPORTS
#define YOURDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define YOURDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Then declare your exported classes as in this example:

```
class YOURDLL_API CLimitOrderBase : public CLimit
{
    ...
    virtual BOOL foo(CLimitInfo &limitInfo);
    ...
};
```

Finally, define `YOURDLL_EXPORTS` in your DLL project (Preprocessor Definitions field under Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor).
This way you wouldn't need manual editing of `.DEF` file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dllexport` is a good idea, but currently I'm just changing one function of a existing big DEF file, and [.def vs _declspec(dllexport)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366228/def-files-c-c-dlls) is beyond this topic.

Thanks for the comment from Hans Passant, I finally figured out how to get mangled C++ function name from Visual Studio (For g++ please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400105/getting-mangled-name-from-demangled-name).)

1. Generate `.map` file:

   - In VS, open the project's Property Pages dialog box
   - Click `Linker` folder
   - Click `Debug` property page
   - Modify `Generate Map File` property.
2. Rebuild the project.
3. Open generated
   `.map` file, search for the function name.
4. Copy the new mangled name to `.def` file

Comment: You can also use `dumpbin /exports` on the DLL to get a list of all the exported names.