# creating a c wrapper for C++ library

Tags: c++, c, api, abi

Is wrapping a c++ library to C via opaque pointers gives a stable ABI interface ? I am clear about ABI interface and why c++ is not having a stable one. This has to do with name mangling and lot other stuff. I know C is very stable in that part. It is also easy to wrap a C library into various other languages compared to C++. These two are driving force to make a c API for my library.

When wrapping a C++ library to C the underlying code is still C++. I my case it is c++ with boost shared ptr and other dependencies.

So since the underlying code is in C++, how the ABI stability is achieved. Or in other words, there is still c++ stuff compiled in the shared library (.so, .dll etc..)

I would like to know how it works. Perhaps someone can provide me with an example that very well explains this stuff.

Comment: What sort of problems do you expect? I mean, you know *why* the C++  ABI us considered unstable, right? Di these same reasons apply in your case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.def files C/C++ DLLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366228/def-files-c-c-dlls)

Comment: Yes, of course there will be c++ stuff compiled into the library. But the interface will have a stable ABI and can be called from pretty much anywhere. Make sure you catch exceptions in API and convert them to old 70s return values.

Comment: @n.m., the problem is abi stability. and the solutions are 1) rewrite the whole code in C. 2) write a C wrapper for C++ code.  I want to know "how it works" for the second option. I still need a c++ compiler even though I only need to build C wrapper dll

Comment: What are *specific* problems associated with ABI stability that apply to you? Specific problems look like this: "when X happens, customers will experience falilure Y doing Z". You should know your Xs Ys and Zs and evaluate them in the case of C-wrapped C++ library. If you don't know these things you perhaps should be asking about them first...

Comment: @n.m. code must be recompiled for all version of the compiler with every minor changes in the API in case of C++ and for C API this is not required as the ABI is stable. I don't know about other specific problems. Please tell me which are other problems. Are you saying the code must be re-written in C?

Comment: "Other specific problems" If your library links to the standard C++ library ABI x, and some other library links to the standard C++ library ABI y, then the two libraries may be unusable together (on some platforms at least). It doesn't matter which interface you export. This is a problem for all C++ libraries. "Are you saying the code must be re-written in C?" Are you saying C++ is unusable for writing libraries? Obviously C++ libraries exist, so somehow people are able to cope with ABI instability.

Comment: thanks @n.m. If I make  C wrapper into a shared library and this shared library is generated on msvc2010. Could this be reused for other version of the same compiler?

Comment: [CppCon 2014: Stefanus DuToit "Hourglass Interfaces for C++ APIs"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVYdHDm0q6Y) might interest you

Comment: Yes, specifically for MSVC this will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create a stable C-Inteface for a C++ implementation.  Of course, the C-Interface only offers C-features.  Still it can be handy to use C++ for the actual implementation.  Here an example where you have a single C++ implementation with function templates and you offer for some variants a C-Interface:

```
// Internal C++ implementation
template <typename T>
void
foo(T &a, const T &b)
{
    // do something
}


// C Interface
extern "C" {

void
sfoo(float *a, const float *b)
{
    foo(*a, *b);
}

void
dfoo(double *a, const double *b)
{
    foo(*a, *b);
}

} // extern "C"
```

So basically the compiler will generate different implementations for `T=float` and `T=double`:

- Of course you don't have function overloading.  So you have to do the name mangling handish.  E.g. `sfoo` for float, `dfoo` for double, ... (You also can do this using the pre-processor in C. But it is not that nice to read and maintain.)
- You don't have references.  So instead of references the interface exposes non-const pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be the stable C ABI of the C compiler for your platform; if done properly, of course.